# How to divide rewards pool linearly along winners

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a reward of 288 tokens (divisible to 8 decimal places) to distribute among the top 64 winners of a daily contest

I'd like this to be fair, and use equal portions so #1 (first place) gets 64 portions, #2 gets 63 portions, down to #64 that gets 1 portion.

How can I express this distribution mathematically, such that I can plug in the position of the winner and get out their reward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sum tokens from 1 to 64, you will get $64×65/2=2080$ tokens which is larger than 288 you have.

However, if you allow 64-th place to receive $x=288/2080 \approx 0.138$ tokens, 63-rd place $2x=0.277$ tokens, ... and 1st place $64x=8.862$ tokens, then you will keep the prize ratio as before and the prizes will sum up to 288.

In general, the amount $k$-th place receives can be calculated as
$$
p(k) = \frac{2Sk}{n(n+1)},
$$
where $S=288$ and $n=64$;